# Oracle SQL Split values to columns

Tags: sql, oracle, split

What suggestions would be to solve such issue in Oracle SQL scripting:

I have a query, which retrieves for specific PO's it's attachment, and this attachment (as a query result), looks something like that: 
Project: xxxxxxx
Task: yyyyyy
Description: rrrrrr
Info: qqqqqqq

So basically it's a pre-made set of values.

so my question will be - is it possible to split it somehow per each column instead of having those mentioned values as one cell value,
so the mentioned outcome would be:
column Project with value xxxx, column task with value yyyyy  etc.

I know, that I can use multiple subselects and then use SUBSTR and INSTR functions, but just thinking - is there any other way how to make it quicker? and especially, if such "columns" could be much more and they could dynamically change (e.g. for one there will be task, but for other  no)?

Comment: is there any pattern for project , task etc.? I mean starting characters or different datatype or something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [REGEXP_SUBSTR](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/functions138.htm#SQLRF06303) to do this:

```
WITH sample_data AS (SELECT 1 ID, 'Project: xxxxxxx Task: yyyyyy Description: rrrrrr Info: qqqqqqq' str FROM dual UNION ALL
                     SELECT 2 ID, 'Project: abcdef Description: fred Info: bloggs' str FROM dual UNION ALL
                     SELECT 3 ID, 'Task: be awesome. Project: the best project ever! Description: my special project Info: only for the best people' str FROM dual UNION ALL
                     SELECT 4 ID, 'Project: Description: james' str FROM dual UNION ALL
                     SELECT 5 ID, 'Project: 151069Task: 99.6Product: Customized something-or-other' str FROM dual)
SELECT ID,
       str,
       regexp_substr(str, 'Project: (.*?)( *Task:| *Description:| *Info:| *$)', 1, 1, NULL, 1) PROJECT,
       regexp_substr(str, 'Task: (.*?)( *Project:| *Description:| *Info:| *$)', 1, 1, NULL, 1) task,
       regexp_substr(str, 'Description: (.*?)( *Project:| *Task:| *Info:| *$)', 1, 1, NULL, 1) description,
       regexp_substr(str, 'Info: (.*?)( *Project:| *Description:| *Task:|$)', 1, 1, NULL, 1) info
FROM   sample_data;
```

Results:

```
        ID STR                                                                              PROJECT                                                                          TASK                                                                             DESCRIPTION                                                                      INFO
---------- -------------------------------------------------------------------------------- -------------------------------------------------------------------------------- -------------------------------------------------------------------------------- -------------------------------------------------------------------------------- --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
         1 Project: xxxxxxx Task: yyyyyy Description: rrrrrr Info: qqqqqqq                  xxxxxxx                                                                          yyyyyy                                                                           rrrrrr                                                                           qqqqqqq
         2 Project: abcdef Description: fred Info: bloggs                                   abcdef                                                                                                                                                            fred                                                                             bloggs
         3 Task: be awesome. Project: the best project ever! Description: my special projec the best project ever!                                                           be awesome.                                                                      my special project                                                               only for the best people
         4 Project: Description: james                                                                                                                                                                                                                        james                                                                            
         5 Project: 151069Task: 99.6Product: Customized something-or-other                  151069                                                                           99.6Product: Customized something-or-other
```

Each of the regexp_substr's works in the same way. Taking the one generating the Project column, it does:

Find the pattern `Project:` that's followed by some (or no) characters, which we put inside brackets to determine the first subexpression: `(.*?)`.
Then we check for the words `Task:`, `Description:`, `Info:` or the end of the line (`$`), each of which may or may not be preceded by zero or more spaces (`*`).

Then we specify the search position and occurrence as 1, the match parameter as null and the output subexpression as 1, since we only want to return the word(s) represented by `(.*?)` that we defined at the start of the search pattern. And voila!

By doing it that way, it doesn't matter in which order the key words appear in, the regexp_substr will be able to extract the correct word(s) you're after for each key word.

The one caveat is that you need to know how many columns you're expecting to return, but you'd hope that this would be something well defined in your data.

---

With a delimiter of \n (newline), you could do this instead, which is more flexible:

```
WITH sample_data AS (SELECT 1 ID, 'Project: xxxxxxx'||chr(10)||'Task: yyyyyy'||chr(10)||'Description: rrrrrr'||chr(10)||'Info: qqqqqqq' str FROM dual UNION ALL
                     SELECT 2 ID, 'Project: abcdef'||chr(10)||'Description: fred'||chr(10)||'Info: bloggs' str FROM dual UNION ALL
                     SELECT 3 ID, 'Task: be awesome.'||chr(10)||'Project: the best project ever!'||chr(10)||'Description: my special project'||chr(10)||'Info: only for the best people' str FROM dual UNION ALL
                     SELECT 4 ID, 'Project:'||chr(10)||'Description: james' str FROM dual UNION ALL
                     SELECT 5 ID, 'Project: 151069'||chr(10)||'Task: 99.6'||chr(10)||'Product: Customized something-or-other' str FROM dual)
SELECT ID,
       str,
       regexp_substr(str, 'Project:( *)(.*)', 1, 1, NULL, 2) PROJECT,
       regexp_substr(str, 'Task:( *)(.*)', 1, 1, NULL, 2) task,
       regexp_substr(str, 'Info:( *)(.*)', 1, 1, NULL, 2) info
FROM   sample_data;
```

Results:

```
        ID STR                                                                              PROJECT                                                                          TASK                                                                             INFO
---------- -------------------------------------------------------------------------------- -------------------------------------------------------------------------------- -------------------------------------------------------------------------------- --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
         1 Project: xxxxxxx                                                                 xxxxxxx                                                                          yyyyyy                                                                           qqqqqqq
           Task: yyyyyy                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
           Description: rrrrrr                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
           Info: qqqqqqq                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
         2 Project: abcdef                                                                  abcdef                                                                                                                                                            bloggs
           Description: fred                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
           Info: bloggs                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
         3 Task: be awesome.                                                                the best project ever!                                                           be awesome.                                                                      only for the best people
           Project: the best project ever!                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
           Description: my special project                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
           Info: only for the best people                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
         4 Project:                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
           Description: james                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
         5 Project: 151069                                                                  151069                                                                           99.6                                                                             
           Task: 99.6                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
           Product: Customized something-or-other
```

You could use any character that wouldn't be present in the value for each keyword as a delimiter and use that in place of \n in the last query.

Comment: Hi, i've tried to perform as you've suggested, but for some reason, my values are empty, while there is the same pattern, as you've described, screenshot in the link: [Screenshot](https://s16.postimg.org/wxuo0pogl/regexp.png) .

maybe you could notice, what I've done wrong?

Comment: I've updated my answer to include your string in my sample_data. As you can see from the results, I get populated project and task fields. This leads me to the point that you need to know the details of all the potential keywords in your string, since you (apparently) don't have a defined delimiter between each item in the string. So, in your case, you'd also need to include ` *Product:` in the list of keywords to be ignored - this is simply to allow the regexp_substr function to tell where the next item starts. It'd be easier if your string had delimiters, e.g. `Project: 12~Task: 1~Key1: a b`

Comment: With delimiters, you wouldn't need to know the names of all potential keywords that could be there, you'd only need to know the ones you were interested in extracting. Btw, I'm running this on 11.2.0.4; what's your version?

Comment: Hmm, actually I think I've found an issue - my string has a whitespace after each text ending, e.g. after project number there was like "enter" (sorted this out in excel.. ).. so by adding \s to the pattern it seems to start working :) 

Thanks for your Help!

Comment: So your text is actually more along the lines of `Project: blahblah<newline>Task: blahblah<newline>...`? If so, that would make newline (`\n`) an ideal delimiter

Comment: I've updated my answer with a version you could use with \n as the delimiter. Another option would have been to keep my original answer, but instead of switching to \s, make the second-to-last parameter in regexp_substr `n` (which tells the . wildcard to match to any character including \n, because otherwise \n is not counted) instead of leaving it null.

Answer (score -1):

But for what i gather, you have the same character to separate the values. For that, you can use the ListAgg function:

```
SELECT LISTAGG(column, ': ')
         WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY name) "List",
   FROM table;
```

Comment: LISTAGG is used for taking values on separate rows and combining them into a single string. It's not used for splitting a string into separate elements.